# String size undesirable output

Tags: c++, string

I am not able to find the bug in this small piece of code. what is wrong with it?

```
string f,s;
f[0] = 'd';
s.append(f);
cout<<f.length()<<"  "<<f<<"  "<<f[0]<<endl;
cout<<s.length()<<"  "<<s<<"  "<<s[0]<<endl;  
Output is : 
0    d
0    d
```

Even if I change `s.length` to `s.size`, the result is the same. Why is `s[0] = 'd'` and `s.size() = 0;`?

Comment: Fix the bug in your code and the mystery will go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the strings are empty when you create them, they contain no characters. `f[0]` is out of bounds, and accessing any element of an empty container is undefined behaviour, so anything can legally happen.

You need to do

```
string f(1, 'd'), s; // creates f with 1 repetition of 'd'
s.append(f);
...
```

Or

```
string f, s;
f += 'd'; // or f.push_back('d'), or f.append('d'), or...
s.append(f);
...
```